# Trying to declare variables by a function to the full script in C#

Tags: c#, variables

I currently try to declare variables from a function to the entire script, like this :

```cs
namespace TestCsharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
             // Some script
             bool bool1 = true;
             string string1 = "string";
             double double1 = 3.4;
        }
       static void Function()
       {
            // More script
            if (bool1 == true)
            {
                // Script again
            }
       }
    }
}
```

BUT an error appears. I can't use 'bool1' in this other fuction.

NO, I can't use my variables like args in Function().

NO, I can't define this at the beginning of my script.

So, can anyone help me ?

Comment: You need to learn about [variable scope](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/).

Comment: @madreflection Yeah, I heard about that. But I failed to use it for my problem... .

Comment: *Where* you declare a variable determines its `scope` or where it can be used.  In general, you cannot 'declare variables from a function to the entire script [sic]'

Comment: @Nayss: It's one of the most fundamental concepts in programming and it's extremely important that you understand it. This problem will continue to vex you until you learn it.

Comment: Oh, ok. I'll try To find a way to solve it by myself. Thanks !

Comment: I don't quite understand.  You say you can't declare them as "globals" ("the beginning of my "script""), and you can't pass them to `Function` as arguments.  What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Those variables are local to the `Main` function.  Therefore they cannot be "seen" by your `Function()`.

I suggest you read up on variable scoping, but the quick answer is:

```
namespace TestCsharp
{
    class Program
    {
        // Note: Declaring at *class* scope (and static)
        static bool bool1;
        static string string1;
        static double double1;

        static void Main()
        {
             // Some script
             bool1 = true;
             string1 = "string";
             double1 = 3.4;
        }
       static void Function()
       {
            // More script
            if (bool1 == true)
            {
                // Script again
            }
       }
    }
}
```

As madreflection points out in the comments, variable scope is an important topic and will explain the results you saw.

Comment: That's helpful - I'll not forget it, thanks - but I have to declare my variables in Main(). Are you sure there's no way to solve my problem with that syntax ?

Comment: This sounds like a prohibitive XY problem.  Perhaps you need to update your question with what you're trying to achieve and why the sane solutions don't fit your needs.